Angluar app Server side rendering deployment on azure app service giving you do not have permission to view this directory or page
you do not have pemission to view this directory or page 
installing packages initially using and building a ssr build
npm i
npm run build:dev:ssr
after that deploying using vs code to the application and after successful deployment , the application is not working


How you are deploying your app? To windows or Linux app service?

If possible please share your code repo.

windows server i am using

Are you following any doc ?

What does you have in your Configuration => Path Mappings => Virtual Application => Physical Path. Image

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

yes i am following doc, and without ssr build deployment i am able to deploy my app on azure app service and use it
i am giving path
site\wwwroot\farmq

Do u have index.html file in the same path?

no i have , index.html on the browser folder
and i tried changing path too => \site\wwwroot\farmq\browser
and now application is working
but still application is not using server.ts file

Refer this doc once

This is a paid version doc

Check the below steps to deploy Angular SSR to Azure App Service.
I have followed the angular.io blog to create angular Application.
ng new myangssr-april23


Refer this blog to configure SSR in angular App.
Local Folder Structure:

Initially even I got the same error.


The issue here is, the app which serves as default page is not in the application root directory.

The default file index.html is under dist =>myangssr-april23\browser folder.




We need to change the physical path of the / root in the Virtual application.

site\wwwroot\dist\myangssr-april23\browser


Output:


This is deploying application , but still  not using server.ts file , want to user server side rendering .
